# Kinesis Analytics: Identify end of substream

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

My Kinesis stream contains session identifiers and for every session, a keepAlive event is sent every second, together with a timestamp. If no more keepAlive events of a session have been sent within an arbitrary time window (say 20 seconds) then no more data will come through from that session and I want to declare that this session has ended. Is there a way to identify the last timestamp of the keepAlive event of that session? The issue is that this can happen at any time so I can't see how time-bounded windows can work in this case.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think it might be because Kinesis Analytics offers the ability to query data in streams via an SQL-like language.

Comment: @TheImpaler Because streaming SQL is (arguably) Kinesis Analytics default language.